# How are SSIS file access rights checked

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS. When I run it from Visual studio as user K, it runs properly. However, when I run it as an other user, A, it claims to complete successfully, but it doesn't do anything (the whole process is inside a foreach loop container that goes through all files in a certain dir). Then I try to run it as a job, and once again it claims to complete successfully, but it doesn't do anything, even though the job owner is a user with near total access.

The question is: how to know which users rights are used to execute an SSIS in a job?

Comment: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/4428/how-do-i-capture-which-userid-ran-the-ssis-package.html

Comment: When run as a job it uses paths as seen from the SQL Server. So if your path is D:\MyPath, it will look at your local D drive in VS, and it will look at the D drive from perspective of the SQL Server when run as a job. You need to crack open the SSIS package logs and do more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, you can access the ssis system variable UserName (`System::UserName`).

You can use it in a FireInformation command in a script task and then the UserName will show up in the execution logs.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely points to the user K not having the desired permissions on the system.

The best practise in this kind of scenarios is to have a service account user with sysadmin priviliges on the server on which data is being loaded. Use the same account first to create a Credential (Security->Credential) and followed by a Proxy Account (SQL Server Agent->Proxies) with access to subsystem - SQL Server Integration Services Package. Now in the SQL Server Agent Job that you create to run this package, use this proxy account to the run the job. Doing so, the package would now be accessible to anyone to run via the SQL Server Agent job.

Use this link as a reference - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/ and check the section - 'Creating a proxy for SSIS Package Execution'